# I want to join two tables to get this kind of an output

Tags: sql, join

| Cust Name | Zip 2022 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | zip1 |
| 101 | zip2 |
| 102 | zip3 |

| Cust Name | Zip 2023 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | zip1 |
| 103 | zip2 |
| 102 | zip4 |

| Cust Name | Zip 2022 | Zip 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | zip1 | zip1 |
| 101 | zip2 |  |
| 102 | zip3 |  |
| 102 |  | zip4 |
| 103 |  | zip2 |

I did try outer join on Cust Name, but it doesn't seem to work in giving me exactly this kind of layout, it's not producing results in ordered manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you use which database engine but in MS SQL Server you can use this sample:

```
drop table if exists #A1
drop table if exists #A2

create table #A1
(
    CustName int not null,
    Zip22 varchar(10)
)

create table #A2
(
    CustName int not null,
    Zip23 varchar(10)
)

insert into #A1 values(101,'zip1')
insert into #A1 values(101,'zip2')
insert into #A1 values(102,'zip3')

insert into #A2 values(101,'zip1')
insert into #A2 values(102,'zip4')
insert into #A2 values(103,'zip2')


select isnull(#A1.CustName, #A2.CustName) as CustName, Zip22, Zip23 from #A1
full join #A2 on #A1.CustName = #A2.CustName and Zip22 = Zip23
```

Comment: You could use `COALESCE()` instead, to get a portable ANSI SQL compliant query. (FIne with SQL Server too.)